# How do you find 2 groups in a URL using regex?

Tags: regex

I am not a programmer by trade but I need to create a rule in Google Tag Manager using regex. My goal is to look at a URL and find two separate group matches in the URL. Here is a sample URL

```
http://123.website.com/?&guid=blahblahblah&page=something&type=abc&adv=abc1234&site={siteID}
```

I originally had this regex below which worked great if it weren't for the "&guid=blahblahblah&page=something&" in between the two groups. How do I check for those two groups in one expression?

```
(http:\/\/)(([0-9])|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))\.website\.com\?(type\=abc)
```

Bonus: How can I make it check for https as well as http?

thx!

Comment: Sure you want to do all that in a single regex? Which language do you use, maybe it has a more convenient feature to handle urls?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... Can you edit it to explain what exactly you want to extract from the URL (with examples of input/output)?

Comment: To match `http` or `https`, use `https?` which will make the `s` optional.

Comment: This answer from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), listed under "Common Validation Tasks", may be of interest: [Using regex to validate a url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After your comments on first version of this answer, I read on page [Tags, Rules, Macros, and the Data Layer](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3284009?hl=en&ref_topic=3441530) of **Google Tag Manager** a little about rules.

Obviously you want a rule which returns **true** if the URL

1. starts with `http://` or `https://`,
2. any number with 1 to 3 digits,
3. `.website.com/`,
4. and contains also `type=abc` within the url.

I can't test this, but the following rule should work:

```
{{url}} matches RegEx https?://\d{1,3}\.website\.com/.*type=abc.*adv=.*
```

The regular expression engine of **Google Tag Manager** hopefully supports those basic regular expressions from Perl regular expression language set.

Explanation:

`http` is a fixed string which must exist in the URL at beginning.

As Sam wrote, the question mark after `s` makes the existence of `s` optional.

`://` is again a fixed string which must exist in the URL after `http` or `https`.

`\d{1,3}` matches any digit (0-9) at least once, but not more than 3 times. So it matches numbers from 0 to 999. Any other character or more digits results in **false** for the rule.

`\.website\.com/` is again a fixed string whereby the point is interpreted as literal character.

`.*` matches twice any character of the URL 0 or more times.

Comment: Ok. I want to be able to check for the following: http://123.website.com/ where "123" is a random number that can be a single digit or 3 digits and and exact match of type=abc

Comment: Maybe it is two separate rules. If that is the case then the answer is easy I think. (https?:\/\/)(([0-9])|([0-9][0-9])|([0-9][0-9][0-9]))(\.tynon\.com) and another rule for type=abc

Comment: Sorry I missed your answer UltraEdit. I have no idea if it supports perl expressions but your answer seems to be what I am looking to do. My goal now is to expand it to include looking for  a match of a third group "adv="

Comment: If parameter `adv=` is always after parameter `type=abc` in the URLs, simply append `adv=` to end of the regular expression after `.*`. Or alternatively insert before `.*` at end of the expression the string `&adv=` if the string `type=abc&adv=` always in the URLs in this form.

Comment: For some reason Google kicks this out {{url}} matches RegEx https?:\/\/([1-9]\d{0,3})\.website\.com\/.*type=abc&amp;adv=abc1234 . This rule doesn't seem to work. Think I need to escape the ampersand?

Comment: The Wikipedia article about [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is also referenced from documentation about **Google Tag Manager**. The ampersand as well as the forward slash are characters with no special regular expression meaning and therefore do not need to be escaped. On the other side escaping `&` and `/` also doesn't matter. But if **Google Tag Manager** converts `&` to `&amp;`, it is better to use simply `.` (any character) instead of `&` in the expression or even better `.*` to match `&` and `&amp;` and everything else between `type=abc`and `adv=`.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier than you think:

```
/https?:\/\/([\d]{1,4})\.website\.com\/.*?&type=(.*?)&.*?/
```

http://regex101.com/r/nU5yP2

Comment: Cool. Looks like this will catch type=abcdefg too. Forgot to mention that type= is sometime longer than 3 characters.

Comment: You want to get the `subdomain` and the `type`, right ?

Comment: Any situations where this fails? The number portion is not likely to exceed 4 digits and will only be numbers. That's important. I don't want matches for letters there. They type= will vary in length and may contain a mix of letters and numbers.

Comment: Great! Did some testing and I found out I need to be able to hard code in the value of "type=" as in "type=abc" instead of just finding the value. Make sense? It needs to be an exact match wheres as the numbers do not. They just need to be present at the beginning.

Comment: Man! Found a place where this fails. Not becuase you code doesn't work but because I need to make an additional match with "adv=abc1234" where abc1234 is a specific value. So far I changed your code which seems to work but I need to extend it to include "adv="   Here is what I have. Quite possible this is poor form. https?:\/\/([\d]{1,4})\.website\.com\/.*?&type=(abc)